# How to get the offset of an image using PHP?

Tags: php

I have an image with the following dimensions:

```
width: 217
height: 122
```

I got these dimensions using the following:

```
<?php

$filename = 'test.png';
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);

// width and height now avaliable in these variables
$width;
$height;

?>
```

Using php how can I get the offset (offset x and offset y) of the image from the center?

Comment: The center of the universe?  There really isn't one. I guess you could just represent offsetX and offsetY as NAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$half_width = $width/2;
$half_height = $height/2;
```

This basically tells you half the width and height of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Center of what?

The browser? -- What browser? *We don't need no stinkin browser!*

PHP runs independant of the browser, so it does not know where the image will end up in the final version the the page, **that** is up to the css and javascript of the aforementioned page

Answer (score 1):

An image by itself does not have any offset.

When you are talking about the offset of an image, you probably mean the offset of the image *embedded in something*. this something can be a web site in a particular browser (which then has nothing to do with PHP), or maybe a page in a PDF document, or a wall in a museum.